# Why can not download the captcha using the following code

Tags: imacros

I was just trying to donwload the captcha from one website everything with educational purposes. But when i use the `ONDOWNLOAD` command, the captcha image never is in the tmp FOLDER.

So what im doing WRONG. I tried using Disabling error notifications, but still never the image is downloaded into the folder.

```
URL GOTO=https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php?ref=fe31773be1c8558db56c7b9f3063ae08
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Up
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Create<SP>New<SP>Account<SP>Please<SP>make<SP>it<SP>at<SP>le*
'SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b EXTRACT=$1

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=examplethenomtest
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:email1 CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:email2 CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:pass1 CONTENT=k1k1k1k1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:pass2 CONTENT=k1k1k1k1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=ID:checkbox CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=ID:checkbox CONTENT=YES

SET url https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php?ref=fe31773be1c8558db56c7b9f3063ae08
SET apikey apikey
SET path C:\tmp\ 
SET file freeditcoin.jpg
SET tw 5

TAB OPEN
'TAB T=1
PROXY ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:0
'TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
'URL GOTO={{url}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
Wait Seconds={{!Var1}}
FILEDELETE NAME={{path}}{{file}}
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{path}} FILE={{file}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:captcha

WAIT SECONDS=11

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
Wait Seconds={{!Var1}}

WAIT SECONDS=6
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:captcha CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
WAIT SECONDS=6
```

Comment: Hi Jesus Garcia!  If Naren's answer solves your problem, please indicate this by clicking the green checkmark to accept it.  If not, please comment or edit your question to explain what remains to be solved.  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code you gave here is the list of issues.

The line having `ONDOWNLOAD` should be immediately followed by download of the captcha, so it should be give as follows.

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
Wait Seconds={{!Var1}}
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{path}} FILE={{file}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:captcha CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

Also notice that in the above code, the last line you were giving the `type` attribute as `IMG` instead of `DIV`.

Regarding the variable `path`, please give some other folder other than the `C Drive` which may be the root of your computer, try giving some path like `C:\Users\asdf\Desktop`. Using such a path, I can see that the image is getting downloaded!

```
SET path D:\
```

Below is the complete code, please let me know if your issues is resolved completely!

```
URL GOTO=https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php?ref=fe31773be1c8558db56c7b9f3063ae08
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Up
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Create<SP>New<SP>Account<SP>Please<SP>make<SP>it<SP>at<SP>le*
'SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b EXTRACT=$1

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=examplethenomtest
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:email1 CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:email2 CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:pass1 CONTENT=k1k1k1k1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=NAME:pass2 CONTENT=k1k1k1k1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=ID:checkbox CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:register ATTR=ID:checkbox CONTENT=YES

SET url https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php?ref=fe31773be1c8558db56c7b9f3063ae08
SET apikey apikey
SET path D:\
SET file freeditcoin.jpg
SET tw 5

TAB OPEN
'TAB T=1
PROXY ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:0
'TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
'URL GOTO={{url}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
Wait Seconds={{!Var1}}
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{path}} FILE={{file}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:captcha CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```